# Do NASDAQ and Russell 2000, 3000 Indices have total return indexes for gross and net? What are they labeled?

Tags: index, spx, nasdaq

Do NASDAQ and Russell 2000, 3000 Indices have total return indexes for gross and net?  What are they labeled?  I know the S&P has a gross TR index with the ticker SPTR and net SPNTR, so I'm wondering if NASDAQ and Russell have the same distinctions?  Tried to use some of the policies and procedures for the two providers but couldn't find an individual manual on all their index policies.

Answer (score 1):

With so many indexes out there it is quite confusing to find what you want!

For Russell 1000 you have RUITR and RUINR.

For Russell 2000 you have RUTTR and RUTNR.

For Russell 3000 you have RUATR and RUANR.

Source: http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/newsalerts/2010/fpnews/fpnews2010-010.pdf

For Nasdaq 100 I found XNDX and XNDXNNR.

Source https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/docs/FS_XNDX.pdf

Comment: It is confusing, and I will say NASDAQ has a cool site (with a lot of dead links so not entirely helpful) and S&P had a relatively navigable site but Russell had so many individual pdfs to comb through.  Thanks!

Comment: https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/

Comment: https://us.spindices.com/